# Why only one folder gets migrated from the SVN branch? (SVN to Git)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to migrate to Git from SVN branches and using following command:

```
git svn clone --authors-file=/c/TEST/authors.txt --prefix=svn/ --branches=/MyScripts/branches/MyProject_1215.br/ https://subversion.mycompany.com/svn/repos/MyProject/ MyScripts/branches/MyProject_1215.br
```

But, once this command completes it just fetches "only one" folder (viz. "ABCDE_12" in this case) from the branch - MyProject_1215.br.

Given below are the console logs:

```
    .
    .
    .
r49975 = 76ef377d1128bbxxxxxxxxx79xxxxxx434089e (refs/remotes/PQRSTU_11)
        A       apply/db/MyProject_1215_some_patch.sql
        A       apply/db/patch/CREATE_INDEX.sql
r50038 = a458ff2ed37092xxxxxxxb7dbyyy971e5yyy5b (refs/remotes/ABCDE_12)
Checked out HEAD:
  https://subversion.mycompany.com/svn/repos/MyProject/MyScripts/branches/MyProject_MR1215.br/ABCDE_12 r50038
```

Any idea why not all the folders (e.g. "PQRSTU_11" and "ABCDE_12" both) under branch MyProject_1215.br are not getting migrated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get all the folders in a branch - just I changed the parameter ***--branches*** to ***--trunk*** in following command:

```
git svn clone --authors-file=/c/TEST/authors.txt --prefix=svn/ --trunk=/MyScripts/branches/MyProject_1215.br/ https://subversion.mycompany.com/svn/repos/MyProject/ MyScripts/branches/MyProject_1215.br
```